# Efeito de radar com CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

Estou tentando fazer uma animação tipo "radar" em volta de uma imagem usando apenas CSS com `@keyframes`. Até consegui chegar a um resultado, exceto pelo fato de que não consigo sincronizar as duas "ondas" do radar, veja:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#container{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: #E2FDFF;
   height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
}

#thumb{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 5px solid #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-image: url(https://cdn2.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/41/11/flat-business-woman-user-profile-avatar-icon-vector-4334111.jpg);
   background-size: 80px 80px;
   background-position: center;
   z-index: 2;
}

.circle1, .circle2{
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid orange;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
}

.circle1{
   animation: circ1 3s infinite;
}

.circle2{
   animation: circ2 1.5s infinite;
}


@keyframes circ1 {
   from{
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   to{
      transform: scale(5);
      opacity: 0;
   }
}

@keyframes circ2 {
   from{
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   to{
      transform: scale(5);
      opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

   <div id="thumb"></div>
   <span class="circle1"></span>
   <span class="circle2"></span>

</div>
```

Pensei em fazer com `animate` do jQuery que tem meios de detectar em que passo a animação se encontra, mas gostaria que fosse apenas com CSS.

O objetivo é sincronizar as duas ondas, onde, quando uma estiver na metade da animação, a outra iniciar, e assim por diante, ou seja, sempre que uma estiver na metade, a outra iniciar, para que haja uma sincronia.

Tentei colocar tempos diferentes em cada uma (`circ1` e `circ2`), mas ambas iniciam ao mesmo tempo e não ficam com a sincronia desejada. Teoricamente ambas as animações deveriam ter o mesmo tempo de duração, apenas uma iniciando após a outra, pois assim haveria uma perfeita sincronia.

É possível e como poderia fazer isso com `@keyframes`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta adicionar um *delay* na animação da segunda "onda" com metade do tempo da animação da primeira onda: `animation-delay: 1.5s;`.

Veja:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#container{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: #E2FDFF;
   height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
}

#thumb{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 5px solid #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-image: url(https://cdn2.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/41/11/flat-business-woman-user-profile-avatar-icon-vector-4334111.jpg);
   background-size: 80px 80px;
   background-position: center;
   z-index: 2;
}

.circle1, .circle2{
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid orange;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
}

.circle1{
   animation: circ1 3s infinite;
}

.circle2{
   animation: circ2 3s infinite;
   animation-delay: 1.5s;
}


@keyframes circ1 {
   from{
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   to{
      transform: scale(5);
      opacity: 0;
   }
}

@keyframes circ2 {
   from{
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   to{
      transform: scale(5);
      opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

   <div id="thumb"></div>
   <span class="circle1"></span>
   <span class="circle2"></span>

</div>
```

> [W3Schools - CSS `animation-delay` Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) (documentação em inglês)

Comment: Mt bom! Valeu! Eu esqueci desse delay rs

Comment: @off-topic: Acho que ficaria mt "daora" com 3 "ondas"! Hehe

Comment: Pois é.. vou ver como fica com 3. :D